# Linux CLI tool for testing audio

Tags: command-line, sound, software-recommendation, headphones

What are some CLI tools that I can use to output a constant sound from all my speakers?

I'm trying to test my speakers (headphones) to make sure they're functional. It seems that if the wire is kinked in *just* the wrong way, it stops playing. But I'm not sure. It's really annoying to test this with a random media file because the I'm never sure if the silence is caused by the file having audio output gaps or the speaker failing.

I just need a simple command that will output a constant stream of sound. Bonus points if I can choose the channel.

What command line utilities can I use in Ubuntu to output a constant sound from the speakers for testing audio?

Comment: an acceptable answer would be a tool to generate a track of pink noise and another tool to play it on loop.

Comment: You can use audacity to create a 1 hour constant sine wave or noise.

Answer (score 10):

The package `alsa-utils` includes a command called [`speaker-test`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/speaker-test.1.html).

#### Install

You can install with

```
sudo apt install alsa-utils
```

#### Run

You can now run this to produce a constant sound

```
speaker-test -t sine -p 1
```

> **Note** You'll want to add `-p 1` else you'll be blasted with a very loud & very annoying sound that **you cannot stop with ctrl+c**. We also change the test from the default "pink noise" to "sine" as it's not such a jarring sound.

Comment: `speaker-test` oh my god why does ctrl+c not exit this

Comment: @MichaelAltfield LOL Ctrl+c will exit it when it's like this `speaker-test -t sine -f 100 -c 2 -p 1` for example.

Comment: good lord thank you. Looks like it's the `-p` that's needed. I can't really hear anything on my speakers with `-f 100`, but this worked great for me `speaker-test -t sine -p 1`

Comment: @MichaelAltfield `speaker-test -t sine -f 450 1> /dev/null & sleep 0.3 && kill -9 "$!"`. 

Answer (score 2):

SoX (The Sound eXchange) can do this.

Install:

```
sudo apt install sox
```

At its simplest, to just play a continuous 440Hz sine tone, you can do

```
play -n synth sine 440
```

`play` expects an input file, `-n` is just used to indicate that there is none.

The `synth` command is quite flexible and can generate wide variety of sounds, including different wave shapes, noise colours, chords and sweeps.

For example, to play a 10 second sine sweep from 20Hz to 20kHz and repeat it five times:

```
play -n synth 10 sine 20-20000 repeat 5
```